# Change Proxy at runtime in Selenium.Webdriver + PhantomJS using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, phantomjs

There is a way to dinamically change proxy in PhantomJS at runtime. Here's the `python` code:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')
driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': '''phantom.setProxy("10.0.0.1", 80);''', 'args' : [] })
```

In `C#` I'm trying:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(@"phantom.setProxy(""10.0.0.1"", 80)");
```

Getting exception:

> {"errorMessage":"Can't find variable:
>   phantom","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"62","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:57378"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":\"phantom.setProxy(\\"10.0.0.1\\",
>   80)\",\"args\":[]}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/513f2130-26b4-11e7-b459-45c0e08b428c/execute"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One limitation in .NET is that you won't be able to do this remotely (via Selenium Grid or similar); you would only be able to do this locally. The code to do so would look something like the following:

```
// WARNING! Untested code written without benefit of
// an IDE. Might not run or even compile without modification.
// First, cast the IWebDriver interface back to the concrete
// PhantomJSDriver implementation.
PhantomJSDriver phantomDriver = driver as PhantomJSDriver;
if (phantomDriver != null)
{
    // If the cast succeeded, the implementation has the
    // ExecutePhantomJS method, which executes script in
    // the browser context instead of the page context.
    phantomDriver.ExecutePhantomJS("phantom.setProxy('10.0.0.1', 80);");
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!